# selenium & python - cant interact with web element

Tags: python, selenium

As my title states, I'm getting an error where my selenium gives me an error saying web element not interactable. Basically, I'm on the Santa Clara county tax parcel website (https://payments.sccgov.org/propertytax/Secured) and trying to use selenium to pull tax bills for land value & tax amounts.I have a for loop with all the tax APN #'s and should loop through each to pull the relevant info. I used this same code last year and everything pulled just fine. For some reason, this year the same code no longer works. I'm guessing that they implemented something that prevents selenium from interacting with the web elements.

I tried using a wait timer as well as time.sleep to make sure the web element loads, but that wasn't the issue. If I use .wait for the element to load before finding, the code just waits forever until timeout.

Appreciate any help! Below is my code:

```
for num, county in zip(lstOfParcelNums, lstofCounties):
    # get Santa Clara's tax website
    if "Santa Clara" in lstofCounties[count]:
        site.get('https://payments.sccgov.org/propertytax/Secured')

        time.sleep(5)

        #Inputting parcel number in search
        apn = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ParcelNumber"]')
        apn.send_keys(num)
        go = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ParcelSubmit"]')
        go.click()

        baldue1 = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_invoiceslist"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[8]').text
        baldue2 = site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_invoiceslist"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[8]').text
        
        landval = site.find_element_by_id('billdetailstablemain').text

        #Populating into excel
        #Data
        fetchedData.cell(count+2,7,value = baldue1)
        fetchedData.cell(count+2,8,value = baldue2)

        wb.save("C:/Users/Custom Gaming PC/Desktop/Python/Projects/2019-20 Tax APN Output.xlsx")
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full Xpath option? This works, though it will be sensitive to any changes in the page.

```
apn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div[1]/input')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Shawn! Thanks for this, it worked perfectly! May I ask, how did you find the full XPATH? I usually inspect the element and then click copy "xpath" but didn't see an option for the full xpath. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi! thanks, I am glad that answer worked for you. I added a screenshot of how I get the full xpath, it's probably easier than explaining; but...open the dev tools menu, then either using the function to click on an item to inspect it OR right clicking -> inspect on the object in the webpage once more will highlight your object int eh Elements pane. from there you can right click on the element in elements pane and select COPY->Copy Full XPath.